# How to prove the identity $\prod_{n=1}^{\infty} (1-q^{2n-1}) (1+q^{n}) =1 $ for $|q|<1$?

Tags: products

Eulers product identity is as follows

\begin{align}
\prod_{n=1}^{\infty} (1-q^{2n-1}) (1+q^{n}) =1
\end{align}

How one can explicitly prove this identity?

Note here $q$ deonotes a complex number satisfying $|q|<1$

Comment: what's $q$?....

Comment: @voldemort, q is just variable

Comment: How do you compute an identity? Do you mean proving that it holds?

Comment: @Wojowu, yes, it is known as Euler identity

Comment: @phy_math Not finding any evidence that this is called "Euler identity."

Comment: Is complex analysis a tool you can use?

Comment: Rewrite it as:

$$\prod(1+x^n)=\prod\frac{1}{1-x^{2n-1}}$$

Then the left side coefficient of $x^N$ is the number of ways to partition $N$ into distinct positive integers, and the right is the number of ways to partition $N$ into odd not-necessarily distinct integers. This reduces it to a combinatorial question, at least.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews [Look here](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/EulerIdentity.html)

Comment: @Winther, Yes, I want to know how to prove(?) compute(?) this equation(identity) holds.

Comment: **1 minute**. $ $

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For $\lvert q\rvert < 1$, define

$$f(q) = \prod_{n=1}^\infty (1-q^{2n-1})(1+q^n).$$

The product is absolutely and locally uniformly convergent on the open unit disk, hence $f$ is holomorphic there, and the product can be reordered and regrouped as desired. It is clear that $f(0) = 1$, and by reordering and regrouping, we have

$$\begin{aligned}
f(q) &= \prod_{n=1}^\infty (1-q^{2n-1})(1+q^n)\\
&= \prod_{n=1}^\infty(1-q^{2n-1})(1+q^{2n-1})\cdot \prod_{n=1}^\infty (1+q^{2n})\\
&= \prod_{n=1}^\infty \bigl(1-(q^2)^{2n-1}\bigr)\bigl(1+(q^2)^n\bigr)\\
&= f(q^2).
\end{aligned}$$

Since for $0 < \lvert q \rvert < 1$ the set $\{ q^{2^k} : k \in \mathbb{N}\}$ has an accumulation point in the unit disk (namely $0$), it follows that $f$ is constant.

Answer (score 5):

We have \begin{align}\prod_{n = 1}^\infty (1 - q^{2n-1})(1 + q^n) &= \prod_{n = 1}^\infty \frac{(1 - q^{2n-1})(1 - q^{2n})}{1 - q^n}\\
&= \frac{\prod_{n = 1}^\infty (1 - q^{2n-1})(1 - q^{2n})}{\prod_{n = 1}^\infty (1 - q^n)}\\
&= \frac{\prod_{n = 1}^\infty (1 - q^{2n-1})(1 - q^{2n})}{\prod_{n = 1}^\infty (1 -q^{2n})(1 - q^{2n-1})}\\
&= 1\end{align}

Comment: Great! it helps me a lot

Comment: Very slick. Might even be easier to see by starting with $$\prod (1-q^n) = \prod (1-q^{2n-1})(1-q^{2n}),$$ which seems obvious, and then divide.

Comment: @Thomas thanks. I wanted to present a calculation that doesn't look like I'm working backwards. I did use that identity at the end though. As you know, it follows from breaking the product into even and odd $n$.

Answer (score 1):

Another approach, similar to Daniel's, without an appeal to properties of holomorphic functions.

$$(1-q)(1+q)(1+q^2)\cdots (1+q^{2^n})\cdots = 1$$

since the partial product is $1-q^{2^{n+1}}$
.

Substituting $q^{2k-1}$, you get:

$$(1-q^{2k-1})(1+q^{2k-1})(1+q^{(2k-1)\cdot 2})\cdots\left(1+q^{(2k-1)\cdot 2^n}\right)\cdots = 1$$

So $$1=\prod_{k=1}^\infty \left((1-q^{2k-1})\prod_{n=0}^\infty \left(1+q^{(2k-1)2^n}\right)\right)$$

Now, ever positive integer $N$ can be written in exactly one way as $(2k-1)2^n$. So we can rearrange.