# Generating function. Inverse.

Tags: generating-functions

Let $D(x)= (x+1)(x^2 +1 ) (x^3 +1 ).... $  and let F(x) be inverse of $D(x)$

I know, that $ D$ is the number of ways to write n as a sum of positive integers without repeated summands. Sums only differing by the order of the summands are counted only once. But I don't see what is inverse for that.
Help me.

Comment: $D$ is not "the number of ways...." $D$ is the generating function for the number of ways. Also, do you mean the inverse function, or do you mean $1/D(x)$?

Comment: An unordered sum is usually called a partition, by the way.

Answer (score 2):

Using the result of [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1118993/7933), we have:

$$D(x)=\prod_{n=1}^\infty (1+x^n) = \prod_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{1-x^{2n-1}}$$

Then:

$$\frac{1}{D(x)} = \prod_{n=1}^{\infty} \left(1-x^{2n-1}\right)$$

So this is the generating function for $a_n=(-1)^np_n$ where $p_n$ is the number of ways to partition $n$ into distinct odd numbers.

Aside: Note that $\frac{1}{D(x)} = \frac{D(-x)}{D(x^2)}$.