# Product of two holomorphic functions defined by infinite product equals to 1.

Tags: complex-analysis, infinite-product, weierstrass-factorization

Let $f(z)=\prod_{n=1}^{\infty}(1+z^n)$ and $g(z)=\prod_{n=1}^{\infty}(1-z^{2n-1}).$

Let $\Omega=\{z\in \mathbb{C}, \; |z|<1\}.$

Since the series $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}|z|^n$, and $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}|z|^{2n-1}$ converges uniformly on every compact $K$ of $\Omega$ then wen can deduce the product converges and $f$ and $g$ are holomorphic on $\Omega$.

But I couldn't prove that $f(z).g(z)=1.$

$\textbf{My method:}$
I decided to determine $f$ explicitly.

Since $f$ is holomorphic and we define $f_n(z)=z^n$, then :
$$\frac{f'}{f}=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{f_n'}{f_n}=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{n.z^{n-1}}{1+z^n}.$$
but I can't go any further

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to prove the identity $\prod_{n=1}^{\infty} (1-q^{2n-1}) (1+q^{n}) =1 $ for $|q|<1$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1118993/how-to-prove-the-identity-prod-n-1-infty-1-q2n-1-1qn-1-for)

Comment: Yes, thank you!